# How can I get all string from JsonReader in ReadJson method?

Tags: c#, json.net

This is part of my custom json converter:

```
 public class ExpandoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Expando).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        /// How can I get all json string from reader at this point like that:
        /// string js= reader.ReadStringToEnd();
```

I dont want to get all serialization string, I need data of converter's targeting.

Ex:

{.......................**{"Id":3,"Name":"MyExpando1"}**}

Comment: I thought you could just do it with `Dictionary<string, object>`as this is an expando object in essence

Comment: No, it does not work because,I can get data via JObject.Load(reader) , But I'm getting error when I trying to iterate JObject and populate my DynamicObject (Expando). Main problem is casting problem.  var j = JObject.Load(reader);
            var expando= new Expando();
            foreach (var item in j)
            { expando.SetProperty(item.Key,item.Value) //TypeCastingException }

Comment: Can't you just read (inside your converter if you wish) it like: `var dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>( reader );` and then loop through the keys of the dictionary?

Comment: It is painful because I have to convert data to Expando, classical Int32 - Int64 problems. I can solve my problem different approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I managed with this is using JObject and loading the reader into the JObject like so:

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jObject);
    }
```